# Floppy disk interface

Tags: embedded

Does anyone know where to get information on the 34 pin floppy disk interface? In particular, I want to be able to read and write to floppy drives from my custom embedded board.

Having a hard time finding info about it because it's so old.

Comment: Strange, I have About 1,230,000 results (0.56 seconds) on Google for 34 pin floppy disk interface...

Comment: How many of those are real or relevant?

Comment: None, because they're about floppies. *runs*

Comment: I just was reading the original Floppy disk specs this afternoon , thinking how little junior EE's know about the complex operations with stepper servo, motor control,  data separator PLL, servo positioner and much more all in a tiny package for $10 at newegg

Comment: I just got all specs and signal waveforms, after just 5 mins of looking into Google hits.

Comment: I am more concerned with the lack of effort on OP side. Here is a lot of info, http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/controlling-floppy-disk-drive-with-arduino

Comment: OP Attn OP. Please reconsider the use of a floppy for your embedded project. It is far far easier to interface an SD card or uSD card and the media can easily be used on a PC or laptop using a cheap memory media USB adapter. Let the dead floppy stay dead.

Comment: I was making board basing on FDC37C65 chip and writing drivers for it several years ago for retro-PC project. If you think it is just so easy as read several web pages and make everything work - you are wrong. I found web pages contain errors, and it took me some time to make piece run properly. Wishing @SectoKia the luck in his endeavor.

Comment: 34 pin floppy interface must be for these newfangled 5 1/4 inch drives.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 To be fair, I don't think the senior EEs knew much either, when they designed floppy disks. For example they didn't know about magnetic fields, gravity or ESD - all common causes for breaking the damn things. And then we shouldn't mention data retention, write cycles or access speed. Somehow I suspect that floppy disks are not going to be remembered as one of mankind's greatest inventions.

Comment: I agree but, yet it was the precursor to HDD magnetic recording devices , which I think are the most complex subsystems , manmade in a tiny box. Having reverse engineered them in the 80's with 100's of detailed margin tests for servo, R/W PLL , RLL, ECC, BER, many closed loop systems, the performance today of defect-free error rates is amazing since they started out at 1e-10 hard error rate, that has grown by a dozen decades at least. Even though I knew enough to be offered the QA Mgr job at Seagate back then, I still only knew <1% of what it takes to make these reliable in qty's of 100k/mo

Comment: and I tortured those HDD's back then to find the weakest links with 1kW radar pulses, drop tests and thermal offtrack, embedded servo now is almost flawless in spite of the tribelectric charges bled off by the ferromagnetic spindle bearing ground brush and xx nanometer flying height on an air bearing in air much cleaner than operating rooms.< Class 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you need a dose of self-injected early 80's technology, here's some light reading.  This tells you a little about the floppy disk interface for those $10 devices with 5.25" floppies, the precursor of 3.5"

http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/westernDigital/WD100x/61-031050-0030_WD1002-05_HDO_OEM_Manual_Jul83.pdf

Here's some more info on the FDC chip interface
ftp://ftp.oldskool.org/pub/drivers/Central%20Point/OptionBoard/website%20mirrors/retro.icequake.net%20Option%20Board%20website%20mirror/dob/files/bleuge/00info/8272sp.htm

it is definitely old-skool, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

From wikipedia's Floppy Disk Controller Article.

How to program the controllers: http://www.isdaman.com/alsos/hardware/fdc/floppy.htm

With a bit of searching:

As of Oct 2016, Floppy disk controllers are still on the market. Microchip sells the FDC37C78

And the wire harness pinout: http://pinouts.ru/HD/InternalDisk_pinout.shtml